# Operating on a list of files using recursion

Tags: recursion, node.js, file, coffeescript, callback

I'm starting just now with CoffeeScript and I found out that I can't solve problems like looping and recursives with just one line.  I would like to improve the code that I just wrote using built-in CoffeeScript helpers.

```
'use strict'
file_system = require 'fs'
Types       = require './types'

Extract =
  each_file: (index = 0) ->
    length  = @files.length
    file    = @files[index]
    if index < length
      Types.read file, @next.bind @
      @each_file index + 1

  next: (file) ->
    @result.push file
    if @result.length == @files.length
      return @cb.clean.call @cb, @result
    @each_file()
    return

  init: (files, cb) ->
    @files              = files
    @cb                     = cb
    @result             = []
    @each_file()
    return

module.exports = Extract
```

The script speaks for itself; I'm doing a recursive function to send files to `Types.read`, and I store the result in the result array.

Comment: And maybe link to used libraries. What is `Types.read` doing?

Comment: It's other code in the app @ferada

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Fake for-loops and comprehensions

At the beginning of your post, you say that you can't always achieve everything with looping in one line in CoffeeScript. When you say that, I assume you are taking about the `each_file`:

> ```
>   each_file: (index = 0) ->
>     length  = @files.length
>     file    = @files[index]
>     if index < length
>       Types.read file, @next.bind @
>       @each_file index + 1
> ```

This is kinda ugly right now because you seem to be using a method to fake a for-loop. Luckily, with CoffeeScript's comprehensions, we can turn this into a simple 1-line expression.

First, we need to be iterating through all of the `@files`. That can be written simply like this:

```
Types.read(file, @next.bind this) for file in @files
```

This is a comprehension that will go through all of the `@files` and substitute the `file` in the `Types.read` call with the current file it's looping over.

Now that we have this, you can remove that

> ```
> file = @files[index]
> ```

line, along with that single `index` parameter. Why? Because, now that we have this loop, we no longer have any of that method-recursion-fake-for-loop-idness.

Along with those, since this is now a comprehensions that loops through all the values in an array, we don't need to do any checking to make sure the index is less than the length.

> ```
> if index < length
> ```

Can be removed. Guess what your method looks like now?

```
  each_file: () ->
    Types.read(file, @next.bind @) for file in @files
```

The above method will do exactly what it was doing before: it will go through all of the files in `@files` and pass it into `Types.read` along with `@next.bind @`.

What's different now?

- It's much shorter and much simpler than what you were doing before. As I already stated, you seemed to be reinventing the `for` loop with that recursion you were doing.
- It's more idiomatic. CoffeeScript has those comprehensions so you can simplify long tasks into a few small and readable lines.

---

## Misc.

> ```
>   init: (files, cb) ->
>     @files              = files
>     @cb                     = cb
> ```

This can be shortened to this:

```
  init: (@files, @cb) ->
```

The CoffeeScript compiler treats parameters with a `@` before them as a name of a property to set to the parameter. For example, `@files` will become:

```
this.files = files
```

in the method body.